# Appending in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the classic many children, one parent problem. I try to add a child to an existing parent without rewriting the parent into my database:

```
def insert_symbol(self, name, group, internal):
    # get the parent object, insert if not existent
    group = self.insert_group(group)

    # append to list of childs in this parent
    group.symbols.append(Symbol(name=name, internal=internal))

    # child is correct!
    print group.symbols[0]

    # nothing in here?!
    print self.__session.dirty
    # nothing to commit?!
    self.__session.commit()
```

The definition of the relationship is listed here:

```
class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'assets_symbolgroup'                                                                                       

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)                                                                 
    name = Column(String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)                                                                    
    symbols = relationship("Symbol", backref="group")

    def __repr__(self):                                                                                                        
        return "<Group(name='{0}')>".format(self.name)                                                                         


class Symbol(Base):                                                                                                            
    __tablename__ = 'assets_symbol'                                                                                            

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)                                                                 
    name = Column(String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)                                                                    
    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('assets_symbolgroup.id'), nullable=False)
    alive = Column(BOOLEAN, default=True, nullable=False)                                                                      
    internal = Column(String(100))                                                                                             

    @property
    def summary(self):
        return {"name": self.name, "group": self.group.name, "internal": self.internal}

    def __repr__(self):                                                                                                        
        return "<Asset(name='{0}', group='{1}')>".format(self.name, self.group)
```

What's the best way to add a child without rewriting the parent?

Thank you for your help
Thomas

Comment: You have two ways of defining the relationship from group to symbols: first you define 'symbols = relationship("Symbol")', and then you have "backref='symbol_group'". This might bring the confusion, try leaving only backref, for example.

Comment: Did that and it removed the Parent = None problem. I have updated the model but still see that the changes made to a Group (e.g. parent) are not persistent despite my attempts to commit

Comment: You probably should add a `parent` to the `session`, which will either end up in the `__session.new` or `__session.dirty`. Otherwise, indeed the session has nothing to commit.